# Erro ao dar o comando Migrate do laravel para postgres

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Caros, boa tarde.
não estou conseguindo realizar o comando migrate no laravel para o postgres. Alterei as configurações, habilitei o driver, mas nada funciona.
Alguma ideia?

```
database.php:

 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

PhpInfo()
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]